# Modulo show equivalence

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $1\leq x\leq y$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$.

Let $a,b\in \left\{0,1,2,\ldots,x,x+1,x+2,\ldots,x+y\right\}$.

In the following, subtractions $a-b$ and $b-a$ are meant modulo $(x+y+1)$.

I would like to show that
we have
$$
b-a\in \left\{x+1,\ldots,y\right\}~~\Leftrightarrow a-b\in\left\{x+1,\ldots,y\right\}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $a\ge b$. Then
$$
b - a \mod x+y+1 = x+y+1-(a-b)\mod x+y+1.
$$
Therefore, if 
$$
x+1 \le a-b \le y,
$$
then
\begin{align}
x+y+1-(a-b) &\le x+y+1 - (x+1) = y. \\
x+y+1 -(a-b) &\ge x+y+1 - y = x+1.
\end{align}
Can you show the other direction yourself now?

Comment: I guess the inequalities are meant with respect to $\mathbb{Z}$? Since we do not have inequalities with respect to modulo.

Comment: Yes, they are with respect to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I have some problem to show it when $a<b$. For $b-a\implies a-b$ it is the same as you did, but how to prove $a-b\implies b-a$ when $a<b$?

Comment: I think I got it. If we assume $a<b$ and $x+1\leq a-b\leq y$ (again the subtraction is meant modulo x+y+1), then $x+1\leq x+y+1-(b-a)\leq y$ where the identity $a-b=x+y+1-(b-a)$ is meant in $\mathbb{Z}/(x+y+1)\mathbb{Z}$ whereas the inequalities are meant with respect to $\mathbb{Z}$. But then, I can just treat this as an inequality in $\mathbb{Z}$ since $b\geq a$ and solve for $(b-a)$.

Comment: That seems correct!